# `ListView` `Mouse Over` define as `transparent` but shows 2 colors

Tags: wpf, listview, styles

My `ListView` `Mouse Over` define as `transparent` but the result is half `transparent`:

[image]

Same with `Selected`:

[image]

Define `Blue` but has 2 colors.

Why is that ?

- Edit

  ```
      <ListView Name="llistview" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" MouseDoubleClick="llistview_MouseDoubleClick" 
            MouseLeftButtonDown="llistview_MouseLeftButtonDown" Margin="0,176,0,166" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" 
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
          <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
                  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
                  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
                  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                  <Style.Triggers>
                      <MultiTrigger>
                          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                      </MultiTrigger>
                      <MultiTrigger>
                          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                              <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF15669E"/>
                          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                      </MultiTrigger>
                      <MultiTrigger>
                          <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                              <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                          </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF15669E"/>
                          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                      </MultiTrigger>
                      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                          <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                      </Trigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
          </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <ListView.Resources>
              <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                  <Grid Margin="-6">
                      <ProgressBar Name="progressBarColumn" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                               Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
                               Height="18" Margin="0" Background="Gainsboro" Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" />
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn, StringFormat={}{0}%}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" Foreground="White" />
                  </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate2">
                  <Grid Margin="-6" >
                      <Slider Name="sliderColumn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" TickPlacement="None"
                              Minimum="0" Maximum="50" Value="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Width="80"
                              TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sliderColumn, StringFormat={}x{0}}" FontSize="11" Foreground="White" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                  </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
              <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarTemplate">
                  <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
              </ControlTemplate>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text }"></Setter>
              </Style>
          </ListView.Resources>
          <ListView.View>
              <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
                  <GridViewColumn Width="495"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding File}" />

                  <GridViewColumn x:Name="SpeedCell"  Width="100"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate2}" />

                  <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}" />

                  <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Packets, StringFormat={}{0:#,0}}" />

                  <GridViewColumn Width="100"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PacketsSent, StringFormat={}{0:#,0}}" />

                  <GridViewColumn x:Name="ProgressCell"  Width="60" Header="Progress" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
              </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
          <ListView.ContextMenu>
              <ContextMenu>
                  <MenuItem Header="Open Capture" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif"
                            Click="MenuItem_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20">
                      <MenuItem.Icon>
                          <Image Height="18" Width="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                          <!--   <Source="C:\Users\rsteinbe\Dropbox\PacketPlayer\PacketPlayer\resources\wireshark.ico" />-->
                      </MenuItem.Icon>
                  </MenuItem>
              </ContextMenu>
          </ListView.ContextMenu>
      </ListView>
  ```

Comment: Probably because the Template has two Borders or something like that. Show us your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ain't gonna be pretty. That extra color is there thanks to an "UpperHighlight" `Rectangle` that is part of the default `ListViewItem` Template, and it is not accessible from outside. So you're only left with overwriting the whole Template.

First of all, add this to your Resources:

```
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#8E6EA6F5" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemHoverFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF1FBFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD5F1FE" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD9F4FF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF9BDDFB" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedInactiveFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFEEEDED" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ListItemSelectedHoverFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFEAF9FF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFC9EDFD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

And then add this to your `ListViewItem` Style:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <!-- ... Your other Setters -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <!--<Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="#75FFFFFF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>-->
                                <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemHoverFill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCCF0FF"/>
                            <!--<Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedFill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#80FFFFFF"/>
                            <!--<Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="#40FFFFFF"/>-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedInactiveFill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFCFCF"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListItemSelectedHoverFill}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF98DDFB"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- ... Your Triggers -->
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Where exactly should i put it ? under what ?

Comment: Ok iput it under  ListViewItem --> style but Property="Template" is not recognize or not accessible

Comment: You have to add it inside your ListViewItem Style, but before the Style.Triggers.

Comment: The other stuff, the resources, you can add them to your ListView.Resources, but I suggest you define those Resources BEFORE they're actually used by the Style and Template... StaticResource references require that the referenced resource is declared beforehand in XAML.

Comment: i put you first code inside Window.Resources and this fine, the second code: inside ListViewItem i have Style and inside Style.Triggers i don't have Setter

Comment: As I said, you have to add it inside `Style`, not inside `Style.Triggers`. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.